# Category not show in Magento admin panel at the time of product update

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created a category with name "root" and also have many sub categories under root category. product adding time all categories show properly. but when we update any product using Magento admin panel, none of them subcategories show under root category. only root category show in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

For creating Categories refer to :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories

For creating products and adding them to the categories refer to:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-products